# Issues getting to the right file when using a google domain pointing to github pages

Tags: html, github, subdomain

Apologies in advance for the painfully newbie question but I am really stuck here.

I have a Google hosted domain: techpalewi.international
That I need to link to file, which is hosted on my github user page: porcoespinho.github.io/techpalehui_international_website/scripts/index.html

So far, I have:

1. Created a CNAME file on my Github project, pointing to the google domain (techpalewi.international)
2. I have created the Custom resource records as advised in github pages (i.e. A pointing to 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154. And a CNAME record pointing to my github pages project repo: porcoespinho.github.io.)

So far I can get to the right page if I type: 
http://techpalewi.international/scripts/index.html

but not if I only type the domain name:
http://techpalewi.international/

Can you please advise how I can get to the right file only pointing the domain name?

Thank you,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to Ryan Burgess @ Netflix who kindly answered this question offline:

It turns out that when one uses a custom domain on GitHub pages, it defaults to landing the project's root page. Thus, the most efficient solution was to move the HTML and CSS files out of the scripts directory and into the root directory. This did the trick masterfully !!!!